# Sanitize JSON for sending with Curl

Tags: bash, curl, json

I have to send a POST request to some service with JSON payload, and it includes some user input. That input variable needs to be JSON-encoded to prevent injection attacks.

Code example that sends requests and parses response JSON to RESP variable:

```
RESP=`curl --connect-timeout "10" -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -X POST -d '{ "Attribute": '"'$USERINPUT'" }',\
        $ENDPOINT | $JQ -r '.key'`
```

How to sanitize, or JSON encode, `$USERINPUT` before creating JSON payload?

Comment: Use a real programming language with a proper JSON library, e.g. Python, Perl, Ruby, whatever.

Answer (score 12):

Using [the `jo` utility](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/), the sanitized JSON document could be constructed using

```bash
data=$( jo Attribute="$USERINPUT" )
```

You would then use `-d "$data"` with `curl` to pass this to the endpoint.

---

Old (but still valid) answer using `jq` instead of `jo`:

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
USERINPUT=$'a e""R<*&\04\n\thello!\''
```

This string has a couple of double quotes, an EOT character, a newline, a tab and a single quote, along with some ordinary text.

```
data="$( jq -nc --arg Attribute "$USERINPUT" '$ARGS.named' )"
```

This builds a JSON object containing the user data as the value for the lone `Attribute` field.

From this, we get

```
{"Attribute":"ae\"\"R<*&\u0004\n\thello!'"}
```

as the value in `$data`.

This can now be used in your call to `curl`:

```
RESP="$( curl --connect-timeout "10" -s \
           -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
           -X POST -d "$data" \
           "$ENDPOINT" | jq -r '.key' )"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python module json.tool from the command line to parse JSON:

```
export USERINPUT="[1,2,3]"
echo $USERINPUT| python -mjson.tool
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
```